# Failure to build Qt for VS2005 and 32 bit

Tags: qt

Although

```
configure -platform win32-msvc2005 -arch x86
```

works well, nmake is immediately giving a fatal error:

```
Qt has not been ported to this architecture
```

I build on a 64 bit Windows 7 machine. Any ideas why this happens?

```
Generating Code...
        cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -O2 -MD -GR -EHsc -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT
 -DQT_UIC -DQT_UIC_CPP_GENERATOR -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_TEXTCODEC -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_NO_CAST
_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_GEOM_VARIANT -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_STL -DQT_NO_SYS
TEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_TEXTSTREAM -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_DEPRECATED -DQT_NODLL
-I"." -I"." -I"cpp" -I"." -I"..\..\..\include" -I"..\..\..\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\include\QtXml" -I"..\..\xml" -I".
.\..\..\mkspecs\win32-msvc2005" -Fotmp\obj\release_shared\ @C:\Users\ronen\AppData\Local\Temp\nm60BD.tmp
cppextractimages.cpp
cppwritedeclaration.cpp
cppwriteicondata.cpp
cppwriteicondeclaration.cpp
cppwriteiconinitialization.cpp
cppwriteincludes.cpp
cppwriteinitialization.cpp
Generating Code...
        link /LIBPATH:"c:\dev\Qt480\src\tools\bootstrap\release" /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYST
EM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='
6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:"tmp\obj\release_shared\uic.intermedia
te.manifest" /OUT:..\..\..\bin\uic.exe @C:\Users\ronen\AppData\Local\Temp\nm7547.tmp
        mt.exe -nologo -manifest "tmp\obj\release_shared\uic.intermediate.manifest" -outputresource:..\..\..\bin\uic.exe
;1
        cd src\winmain\ && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Debug all

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -nologo -Zm200 -Zc:wchar_t- -Zi -MDd -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -GR -EHsc -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -
DQT_LARGEFILE_SUPPORT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT3_SUPPORT -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILD
ER -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -I"..\..\include" -I"
tmp" -I"..\..\include\QtCore" -I"c:\dev\Qt480\include\qtmain" -I"tmp\rcc\debug_shared" -I"tmp" -I"..\..\include\ActiveQt
" -I"tmp\moc\debug_shared" -I"..\..\mkspecs\win32-msvc2005" -Fotmp\obj\debug_shared\ @C:\Users\ronen\AppData\Local\Temp\
nm7813.tmp
qtmain_win.cpp
c:\dev\qt480\include\qtcore\../../src/corelib/arch/qatomic_arch.h(96) : fatal error C1189: #error :  "Qt has not been po
rted to this architecture"
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to supply the arch parameter.  From the source of [qatomic_arch.h](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/0d95e16c296aa04b68b86383aa1ffad27f9eef6c/src/corelib/arch/qatomic_arch.h) it seems that it's skipped the `QT_ARCH_WINDOWS` section.  So try building without `-arch`.  Also ensure that you're building from a 32-bit Visual Studio command prompt (that's assuming that VS2005 had a 64-bit compiler -- I can't remember whether it did).  If you build with VS2008 then you need to launch a 32 or 64-bit Visual Studio command prompt as appropriate.

Comment: It seems to have passed the phase where it failed before. Building under VS2005 without the "-arch" parameter. So far looking good. it'll take all night to build this, I'll know for sure in the morning. thanks for your help. I'll go ahead and mark your answer for the time being.

Comment: Glad it got a bit further.  Try also using jom to speed up your builds.  Doesn't work for everyone, but if you have a multi-core machine you may find it builds 2-4x quicker http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2009/03/27/speeding-up-visual-c-qt-builds/

Answer (score 0):

Try to build it with minigw. I think that would help you when you are performing nmake. I had problem about building with nmake. Try to build it on higher version of VS2008>

Comment: What's the runtime implication of doing this? Will my application be able to link against DLLs/LIBs built with VS2005 if it also uses the MiniGW built QT? what about side by side C runtime DLL deployment? what extra baggage will MiniGW bring?

Comment: I have not made any test about comparing MiniGW and VS2005, at my knowledge I think it should link it normally. You can always try and see if it's working. I am using MiniGW only. I am using it for android and for desktop. And everything works well. My suggestion is to try it and ofc make backup before.